# RegExp used to validate the website URL not working with arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

I tried this and it works:

```
var regexp = /^(https?|ftp):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(:[a-zA-Z0-9.&%$-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}|([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(:[0-9]+)*(\/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.,?'\\+&%$#=~_-]+))*$/;
        

if(self.shop_website().indexOf("http://") < 0 && self.shop_website() != ""){
    self.shop_website("http://" + self.shop_website());
}
if(regexp.test(self.shop_website()) || self.shop_website() == ""){
....
}
```

But it didn't work when I tried to use it with an array:

```
var domains =[".aero",".biz",".cat",".com",".coop",".edu",".gov",".info",".int",".jobs",".mil",".mobi",".museum"]
domains = domains.join('|');
domains = domains.replace(/\./g,'')
domains = domains + "|";
var regexp = new RegExp("/^(https?|ftp):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(:[a-zA-Z0-9.&%$-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}|([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.("+domains+"[a-zA-Z]{2}))(:[0-9]+)*(\/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.,?'\\+&%$#=~_-]+))*$/");'
```

This code is used to validate the website URL, for example, [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), google.com.uk.

Comment: So how can I solve that problem? domains is string in that part.

Comment: Have you tried removing the dots in your domains array?

Comment: Instatiation doesn't require `//` try `var regexp = new RegExp("^(https?|ftp):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(:[a-zA-Z0-9.&%$-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}|([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.("+domains+"[a-zA-Z]{2}))(:[0-9]+)*(\/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.,?'\\+&%$#=~_-]+))*$");`

Comment: There are much more TLDs than the ones in your array, have a look at http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using:

```
var regexp = new RegExp("^(https?|ftp):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(:[a-zA-Z0-9.&%$-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]?)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}|([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.("+domains+"[a-zA-Z]{2}))(:[0-9]+)*(\/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.,?'\\+&%$#=~_-]+))*$");
```

- There should be no enclosing `/.../` while using `RegExp`
- You need to double escape DOTa or anywhere you have single `\`